# Inserting a code block into Oracle DB using PHP

Tags: php, sql, oracle, sql-insert

I'm trying to execute a block of insert statements using PHP into a table in our Oracle DB...

```
/*$hostInsert looks like this (new lines are made with <br>'s)...
 *
 *BEGIN
 *INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('', 'testa', 'testa2');
 *INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('', 'testb', 'testb2');
 *INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('', 'testc', 'testc2');
 *END;
 *
 */

try{
    $db->execute($hostInsert);
}catch(Exception $e){
    $mes = $e->getMessage();
    echo $mes;
}
```

Unfortunately the code above doesn't appear to be working and doesn't print any sort of error message...

My question, is this possible? Is this due to the breaks I've inserted into string, or is there a better way to do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So are you saying the command you send to the database has `<br>`s for   line breaks?  If so, yes, that is a problem.

Comment: Right so it really looks like... BEGIN<br>
 *INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('', 'testa', 'testa2');<br>
 *INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('', 'testb', 'testb2');<br>
 *INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('', 'testc', 'testc2');<br>
 *END;

Comment: Just to make sure, your `TABLE` is the actual name of the table you are inserting into right? Also how many columns does the table have?

Comment: This has the correct # of values and the table name is correct as well. My question is, can you execute a block of these insert statements in this format? W/O the <br>'s

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use HTML line break syntax in an SQL query.  That won't be understood by the database.  You need to remove any `<br>` from the query before you execute it.

Comment: Okay I went ahead and removed the <br>'s but it still doesn't work. Is it possible to execute a block of insert statements through PHP? Am I going down the right route?

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I appreciate the help but I figured out the issue on my own. It was my own dumb mistake. I'm executing multiple insert statements on 2 tables and it turns out there were dependencies in which we couldn't insert a record in one table without having a record mapped to it in the other. I ultimately swapped the order of my execute statements and it wound up working.